# Writing tests for ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: asp.net, web-services, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I noticed in one of the [ASP.NET Web API getting started tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) that the option to add a test project is disabled and I'm not sure why that would be.  Would I just test an ASP.NET Web API project like any other MVC project?

I'm prototyping something and I'm being lazy and just using an MVC project and returning JSON from some controllers to mock up a web service.  As things start getting a bit more serious, I need to start doing things "more correctly".

So how should I write tests for an ASP.NET Web API project and, more broadly, how could I automate the testing of the actual web service?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this like so:

```
  [TestFixture]
    public class CountriesApiTests
    {
        private const string BaseEndPoint = "http://x/api/countries";

        [Test]
            public void Test_CountryApiController_ReturnsListOfEntities_ForGet()
            {
                var repoMock = new Mock<ISimpleRepo<Country>>();

                ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<ISimpleRepo<Country>>().Use(repoMock.Object));
                repoMock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(new List<Country>
                                                                           {
                                                                               new Country {Name = "UK"},
                                                                               new Country {Name = "US"}
                                                                           }.AsQueryable);

                var client = new TestClient(BaseEndPoint);
                var countries = client.Get<IEnumerable<CountryModel>>();
                Assert.That(countries.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
            }
    }
```

TestClient code:

```
public class TestClient
    {
        protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        protected readonly string _endpoint;

        public HttpStatusCode LastStatusCode { get; set; }

        public TestClient(string endpoint)
        {
            _endpoint = endpoint;

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new WebApiDependencyResolver());
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });                                

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpServer(config));            
        }       

        public T Get<T>() where T : class
        {
            var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(_endpoint).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // need this to throw exception to unit test

            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
        }
    }
```